# Power Automate Recurrence Trigger : how to find last 5 working days of the month?

Tags: power-automate, recurrence

I need to create a recurrence in Power Automate so that it only runs in the last 5 working days of the month. I can't use a generic rule because months like February are different.

What I have done so far was using a similar recurrence that finds the last working day of the month but need help with optimising it for the last 5 working days instead.

[image: Full view]

[image: Top Part]

[image: Middle part]

[image: Bottom part]

The logic is that the flow runs every day and looks at the first day of the next month, then comes backwards to find the first working day and excludes Monday-Sunday. however, I need it to find the last 5 working days instead of 1.

Also the functions used are like this:

```
startOfMonth(addToTime(variables('Date'),1,'Month'))
addDays(variables('DateCountDown'),-1)
dayOfWeek(variables('DateCountDown'))
@and(not(equals(variables('DayOfWeek'), 0)), not(equals(variables('DayOfWeek'), 6)))
addDays(variables('DateCountDown'), -1)
dayOfWeek(variables('DateCountDown'))
```

disclaimer: I am not a pro user of power automate and found this flow in an old GitHub repository (written by Michael Ziemba) - thanks all for your help.

---

in response to teylin:

1. I get today   (as before)
2. I get first day of next month (as before)
3. I go 7 days down now > addDays(variables('DateCountDown'),-7)
4. I initialize a variable to find week day > dayOfWeek(variables('DateCountDown'))
5. then varCounter variable as you said (varCounter > integer > 1)
6. then DO UNTIL loop until varCounter = 7
7. inside the loop I have 3 conditions: day of week <> 0 , dayof week <> 6 and formatDateTime(variables('DateCountDown'), 'dd-MM-yyyy') = formatDateTime(variables('Date'), 'dd-MM-yyyy')  (to check today)
8. then trigger my stuff if yes,
9. increment varCounter by 1

[image: teylin-A]

[image: teylin-B]

[image: teylin-C]

---

Answer (score 2):

Don't overthink this. Conceptually:

- Get the first day of the next month (you already know how to do this)
- get DayX by subtracting 7 from that date (you already do this with 1, now do it with 7)

By definition, 2 of the seven days between that DayX and the next month will be on a weekend. So, next, you start a loop that runs 7 times. Inside the loop, you have these actions:

- add a condition with the following two checks
- check if DayX is a weekday (you already know how to do this) AND
- check if DayX is = today
- In the Yes branch of the condition run the steps that you want to run on the last 5 weekdays, in the No branch do nothing
- below the condition step, increment DayX by one day
- loop

For the loop, first initialise a counter variable to the value 1. Add a Do Until action and set it to run until the counter is greater than 7. Inside the loop, do your calculations and your condition etc. As the last step of the loop, increment the counter variable by 1.

[image]

Comment: Hi @teylyn and thanks for your answer. seems reasonable. but can you help me with the second part where I need to create the loop? I've added a loop after decreasing 7 days but now can't initialize a new variable to check if it's weekday or not. mainly these 3 steps:

(1) So, next, you start a loop that runs 7 times
(2) increment DayX by one day
(3) loop

Comment: You are already using a loop, too. I've added a screenshot with some core elements.

Comment: thanks again for the screenshot. I guess I have done it but not sure correctly or not!
below are my steps:
(see original post)

Comment: Please don't post your updates into the question. To see if it works, just check the flow run and go through the steps to see the results of each step. If anything goes wrong, you can see exactly what you need to change.